# Call child function from parent object

Tags: java, parent-child

i have 3 class: 
"Player", "Item" parent of "Weapon"

in Player i create a "inventory" like in a game with an arraylist

`public ArrayList<Item> inv = new ArrayList<Item>();`

i have this function located in Weapon class

```
public void dispWeaponStats() {
        System.out.println( "Nom de l'item : " + super.nameItem );
        System.out.println( "D\u00e9gats de l'item : " + this.damageItem );
        System.out.println( "Durabilit\u00e9 de l'item : " + super.durabilityItem + "\n" );
}
```

I want to call this function from something like this 
`inv.get(0).dispWeaponStats()`
But it show me "The method dispWeaponStats() is undefined for the type Item".

i want him to like detect that this Item is a Weapon and he will got search this function in Weapon

Someone can help me, i'm new at Java..

Weapon Class :

```
class Weapon extends Item {

    private int damageItem;

    public Weapon(String nameItem, int damageItem, int durabilityItem) {
        super(nameItem,durabilityItem);
        this.damageItem = damageItem;
    }

    public void dispWeaponStats() {
        System.out.println( "Nom de l'item : " + super.nameItem );
        System.out.println( "D\u00e9gats de l'item : " + this.damageItem );
        System.out.println( "Durabilit\u00e9 de l'item : " + super.durabilityItem + "\n" );
    }

}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item  {

    protected String nameItem;
    protected int durabilityItem;

    public Item(String nameItem, int durabilityItem) {
        this.nameItem = nameItem;
        this.durabilityItem = durabilityItem;
    }
    .....
```

Comment: Make sure that `Weapon` is a subclass of `Item`. You would then probably have a `displayStats()` method, which is implemented by each subclass of item to display things. I will add an example in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make something like this:

**Item.java**

```java
public interface Item {
    String getName();
    int getDurability();
    void displayStats();
}
```

**Weapon.java**

```java
public class Weapon implements Item {

    private final String name;
    private final int damage;
    private int durability;

    public Weapon(String name, int damage, int durability) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.durability = durability;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDurability() {
        return durability;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayStats() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Damage: " + damage);
        System.out.println("Durability: " + durability);
    }
}
```

**Armor.java**

```java
public class Armor implements Item {

    private final String name;
    private final int protection;
    private int durablity;

    public Armor(String name, int protection, int durablity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.protection = protection;
        this.durablity = durablity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getProtection() {
        return protection;
    }

    public int getDurablity() {
        return durablity;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayStats() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Protection: " + protection);
        System.out.println("Durability: " + durablity);
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Item> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add weapons
        inventory.add(new Weapon("Dagger", 6, 100));
        inventory.add(new Weapon("Longsword", 12, 75));
        inventory.add(new Weapon("Battle Axe", 18, 80));

        // Add armor
        inventory.add(new Armor("Metal helmet", 30, 80));
        inventory.add(new Armor("Leather boots", 10, 80));

        System.out.println("--------------------");
        for (Item item : inventory) {
            item.displayStats();
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

You would probably create an abstract base class like `ItemBase` for your items with common properties, so that you don't need to rewrite the same things in every subclass of `Item`.

Comment: I want to create a inv arraylist of objects Item
then create multiple childs of Item like "Weapon" "Armor" and "Potion"
and i want them to be stocked in the same ArrayList<Item>

and i can't do that with what you did (or maybe i'm just dumb ?)

Comment: As long, as all of your Items, you want to store in the `ArrayList` implement the `Item` interface, you can put inside, whatever you want.

Comment: How can i call `getDamage()` who is in Weapon from another class ?
with `item.getDamage` ? it don't work

Comment: You have to cast the weapon first, like so: `Weapon item = (Weapon) inventory.get(0);` You should check the type first. Or you have different inventory slots for you special types of items, or methdods filtering out only your weapons.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after renaming everything it work exactly as i wanted
Once again thanks !